# hide value by a hyperlink

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, hyperlink

I was asking that : whenever I pass a value by a link then it looks like this:

```
<a href="some.jsp?someid=<%=something%>">Click here to view details</a>
```

Now when i click on that hyperlink i am going to **some.jsp** and retrieving value of search like:

```
request.getparameter("someid");
```

**But** I am also seeing all those sensitive details in the browser URL, which is vulnerable. I want to hide all these details so that nothing will be shown in the browser's url but processing will be done internally. How can i do it? Please ignore jsp tags, I am learning JSTL and will soon replace scriplets but initially i want to implement it on jsp tags. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd turn the link into a button you could pass it as a hidden POST value and have your some.jsp page read that. For example:

```
<form method="post" action="some.jsp">
    <input type="hidden" name="someid" value="<%=something%>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Click here to view details" />
</form>
```

Then on your some.jsp, you can read the `someid` POST value and do with that whatever you want.

Comment: ok but in hyper link for each student different roll number was coming and after clicking that hyperlink students can view their details based on their roll numbers but in button can i see roll number so that after clicking the button can i see details?

Comment: @tom: If the roll number is the "someid", than they can see their specific details based on that. If the roll number is another value, just pass another hidden value to the some.jsp page through the same form.

Answer (score 1):

First of all , if you want to show sensitives stuffs in URL, Why are you usng GET request.
You should use POST request. Store the value of someid in request attribute.

Comment: POST request in a hyperlink??? It is not a form, a hyperlink. Can i place a hyperlink in a form...setting it to POST method?

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt and decrypt the value of someid for doing it. See the example given here:
[Encrypting a String with DES](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/desstring.html)

Comment: ok but with encryption and decryption any external user can also do it thus can get sensitive values by decryption....then what's the use of this?

Comment: They cannot decrypt it unless they know the key

Comment: ok ya i got it but do you think it will be quite safe for sensitive information or simply if i can hide all these stuffs in that url so that nobody can see anything, which one is better my friend?

Comment: In my system, I've enrypted such sensitive data